# Disable specific days of the week on jQuery UI datepicker NOT ALL

Tags: jquery

I want to disable certain days.

Disable all Tu, Th:

```
var closedDays  = ["2","4"];
```

I want enable this array date

```
var OpenDate    = ["23,12,2014","25,12,2014"];
```

The 23-12-2014 is TU and 25-12-2014 is TH

```
jQuery("#jform_date").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: nonWorkingDates,
    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
    minDate: 0
});

jQuery("#jform_date").datepicker();

function nonWorkingDates(date) {
    var day = date.getDay();
    // Disable all Tu, Th
    var closedDays = ["2","4"];

    // I want enable this date 
    var OpenDate = ["23,12,2014","25,12,2014"];

    for (var i = 0; i < closedDays.length; i++) {
        if (day == closedDays[i][0]) {
            return [false];
        }
    }
    return [true];
};
```

Comment: Do you have to use this exact format? `"23,12,2014"`

Comment: all format is good i use php

Answer (score 2):

```
function nonWorkingDates(date) {
    var day = date.getDay();
    var year = date.getYear();
    var month = date.getMonth()+1; // JS months start at 0
    var date = date.getDate();
    var fullDate = date+','+month+','+year;
    // Disable all Tu, Th
    var closedDays  = [2, 4];
    // I want enable this date 
    var OpenDate    = ["23,12,2014", "25,12,2014"];
    return [$.inArray(day, closedDays) == -1 || $.inArray(fullDate, OpenDate) != -1];
}
```

`$.inArray()` uses strict comparisons, so I changed the elements of `ClosedDays` from strings to integers.